# Does Ligntdm require specific configuration or clean-up of SDDM files after install on Lubutu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, login, lightdm, systemd, vnc

I'm evaluating Lubuntu 20.04 for a custom application.   Customisations include a static IP address, vnc service, an auto-login for a non-admin user and halting of all non-essential services to minimise impact on a long-running background task.

I've configured an x11vnc systemd service based on settings that work on Ubuntu 20.04. The configuration requires Lightdm be installed.  It does not appear as an explicit dependancy however the service fails unless Lightdm is installed. I assume it has do do with starting Xwindows.  I initially had some password glitches logging in as admin but the service worked.  However, after creating a non-admin user I could not login back in as that user as the password was not recognised and auto-login did not work.  There is apparently a problem with Lightdm on Lubuntu/Lxqt that puts my customisation at risk. (Same result after several trials)

It is unclear to me whether the problem is entirely to do with Lightdm configuration or a conflict with remaining SDDM files.  It is also unclear whether the solution is to fix Lightdm (acceptable), find a way for the x11vnc service to run under SDDM without installing Lightdm (preferred), or use an alternative vnc service that works with standard Lubuntu (good).

Answer (score 1):

I've given up on light versions of Linux as this is the second version that led to a technical impasse after attempting to do an upgrade or install.  I've upgraded to Ubuntu Mate with minimal installation option. Lightdm installed OK without the same issues.  Now I need to work out what services and utilities I can halt in order to minimise resource contention with a 3D render program using multiple cores/threads.  Welcome comments from anyone with similar challenge.

Thank you for the interest and help.